# Creating TIN from points using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, tin

I need to create a TIN from a point shapefile with water elevation values. I need the TIN to extend to the end of a floodplain polygon (yellow lines in screenshot).

Currently the TIN created stops where the points stop (see screenshot). I would like to extrapolate the elevations until the edge of the polygon to cover the whole floodplain.

How could I do this?

[image]

Comment: You can't extrapolate that far with any reliability. You need more data.

Comment: Try to interpolate boundary (polyline) to 3d shape using DEM if available.

Comment: Can you explain why you need a TIN?  Can you convert the polygon to a polygonZ with elevation values in the same vertical datum as your points.  Then add the polygon as an input in the Edit TIN operation as either a hard or soft clip polygon?  Alternatively, what about making a Voronoi diagram (Thiessen polygons) around your points and then clipping those resulting polygons to the floodplain data?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help! I could convert the polygon to Z values for one of the scenarios where the point values match the polygon elevation, but we have other 2 sea level rise scenarios (point shapefiles) that do not match the polygon elevation. I will try the Voronoi diagram next.

Comment: Update: After doing research, I have gotten down to using either IDW or Kriging methods. I am doing tests with both of them so determine which gives me better results.